# Fluentd pods running via daemonset getting terminated with warnings on google container engine

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, google-kubernetes-engine, td-agent

I am trying to run fluentd as a daemonset on kubernetes cluster (GKE). The config is getting parsed successfully, then the plugins are receiving shutdown signal with few warn messages. There are no error messages. I tried increasing the verbosity level and following is the output of pods:

```
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:46 +0000 [info]: #0 fluent/log.rb:322:info: starting fluentd worker pid=9 ppid=1 worker=0
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:46 +0000 [info]: #0 fluent/log.rb:322:info: fluentd worker is now running worker=0
fluentd-sr764 fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:50 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.info" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={"worker"=>0, "message"=>"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
fluentd-dhwnx fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:51 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.info" time=2018-09-08 11:02:46.029522363 +0000 record={"worker"=>0, "message"=>"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:51 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.info" time=2018-09-08 11:02:46.538377182 +0000 record={"worker"=>0, "message"=>"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
fluentd-sr764 fluentd 2018-09-08 11:02:55 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.warn" time=2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000 record={"error"=>"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>", "location"=>"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'", "tag"=>"fluent.info", "time"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, "record"=>{"worker"=>0, "message"=>"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\" location=\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\" tag=\"fluent.info\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\"worker\"=>0, \"message\"=>\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\"}"}
fluentd-sr764 fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:10 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.warn" time=2018-09-08 11:03:05.168427649 +0000 record={"error"=>"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>", "location"=>"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'", "tag"=>"fluent.warn", "time"=>2018-09-08 11:03:00.165843014 +0000, "record"=>{"error"=>"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>", "location"=>"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'", "tag"=>"fluent.warn", "time"=>2018-09-08 11:02:55.156840516 +0000, "record"=>{"error"=>"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>", "location"=>"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'", "tag"=>"fluent.warn", "time"=>2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000, "record"=>{"error"=>"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>", "location"=>"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'", "tag"=>"fluent.info", "time"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, "record"=>{"worker"=>0, "message"=>"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\" location=\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\" tag=\"fluent.info\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\"worker\"=>0, \"message\"=>\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\"}"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\" location=\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\" tag=\"fluent.warn\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000 record={\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.info\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"worker\"=>0, \"message\"=>\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.info\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}\"}"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\" location=\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\" tag=\"fluent.warn\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:55.156840516 +0000 record={\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.warn\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.info\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"worker\"=>0, \"message\"=>\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.info\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.warn\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000 record={\\\"error\\\"=>\\\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\\\", \\\"location\\\"=>\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\", \\\"tag\\\"=>\\\"fluent.info\\\", \\\"time\\\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \\\"record\\\"=>{\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\\\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\\\\\" location=\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\" tag=\\\\\\\"fluent.info\\\\\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\\\\\"worker\\\\\\\"=>0, \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\\\\\"}\\\"}\"}"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\" location=\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\" tag=\"fluent.warn\" time=2018-09-08 11:03:00.165843014 +0000 record={\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.warn\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:55.156840516 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.warn\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"error\"=>\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\", \"location\"=>\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\", \"tag\"=>\"fluent.info\", \"time\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \"record\"=>{\"worker\"=>0, \"message\"=>\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.info\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.warn\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000 record={\\\"error\\\"=>\\\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\\\", \\\"location\\\"=>\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\", \\\"tag\\\"=>\\\"fluent.info\\\", \\\"time\\\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \\\"record\\\"=>{\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\\\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\\\\\" location=\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\" tag=\\\\\\\"fluent.info\\\\\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\\\\\"worker\\\\\\\"=>0, \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\\\\\"}\\\"}\"}, \"message\"=>\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\" location=\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\" tag=\\\"fluent.warn\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:55.156840516 +0000 record={\\\"error\\\"=>\\\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\\\", \\\"location\\\"=>\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\", \\\"tag\\\"=>\\\"fluent.warn\\\", \\\"time\\\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000, \\\"record\\\"=>{\\\"error\\\"=>\\\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\\\", \\\"location\\\"=>\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\", \\\"tag\\\"=>\\\"fluent.info\\\", \\\"time\\\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \\\"record\\\"=>{\\\"worker\\\"=>0, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\"}, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\\\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\\\\\" location=\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\" tag=\\\\\\\"fluent.info\\\\\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\\\\\"worker\\\\\\\"=>0, \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\\\\\"}\\\"}, \\\"message\\\"=>\\\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\\\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\\\\\" location=\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\" tag=\\\\\\\"fluent.warn\\\\\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:50.153922217 +0000 record={\\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"location\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"tag\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"fluent.info\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\"=>2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000, \\\\\\\"record\\\\\\\"=>{\\\\\\\"worker\\\\\\\"=>0, \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\\\\\"}, \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\"dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" location=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" tag=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fluent.info\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" time=2018-09-08 11:02:45.151774166 +0000 record={\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"worker\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"=>0, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"=>\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fluentd worker is now running worker=0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\"}\\\"}\"}"}
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:24 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: preparing shutdown output plugin type=:elasticsearch_dynamic plugin_id="kubelet_out_es"
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:24 +0000 [info]: #0 fluent/log.rb:322:info: shutting down output plugin type=:elasticsearch_dynamic plugin_id="kubelet_out_es"
fluentd-dhwnx fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-2.10.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch_dynamic.rb:268:in `eval'" tag="fluent.debug" time=2018-09-08 11:03:24.151685730 +0000 record={"message"=>"fluentd main process get SIGTERM"}
fluentd-sr764 fluentd-dhwnx fluentd-7przp fluentd fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on filter plugin type=:parser plugin_id="myapp_filter"
fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on filter plugin type=:parser plugin_id="myapp_filter"
fluentd-dhwnxfluentd-sr764  fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:322:info: Worker 0 finished with status 0
fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:322:info: Worker 0 finished with status 0
2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on output plugin type=:elasticsearch_dynamic plugin_id="kubelet_out_es"
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on output plugin type=:elasticsearch_dynamic plugin_id="apiserver_out_es"
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on output plugin type=:elasticsearch_dynamic plugin_id="out_es"
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:25 +0000 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:302:debug: calling terminate on filter plugin type=:parser plugin_id="myapp_filter"
fluentd-7przp fluentd 2018-09-08 11:03:26 +0000 [info]: fluent/log.rb:322:info: Worker 0 finished with status 0
```

fluentd.conf:

```
@include systemd.conf
@include kubernetes.conf

# Start of fluent.conf
<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.myapp-provider**.log>
  @type parser
  @id myapp_filter
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /^[A-Z]/
    format1 /^(?<level>[^ ]*)[ \t]+\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<request>[^\]]*)\] (?<class>[^ ]*): (?<message>.*)$/
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L %z
  </parse>
</filter>

<match kubelet>
   @type elasticsearch_dynamic
   @id kubelet_out_es
   log_level info
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   #user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
   #password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
   index_name fluentd-${tag_parts[0]+ "-" + Time.at(time).getlocal("+05:30").strftime(@logstash_dateformat)}
   include_timestamp true
   #logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
   #logstash_format true
   <buffer>
     flush_thread_count 8
     flush_interval 5s
     chunk_limit_size 2M
     queue_limit_length 32
     retry_max_interval 30
     retry_forever true
   </buffer>
</match>

<match kube-apiserver>
   @type elasticsearch_dynamic
   @id apiserver_out_es
   log_level info
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   #user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
   #password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
   index_name fluentd-${tag_parts[0]+ "-" + Time.at(time).getlocal("+05:30").strftime(@logstash_dateformat)}
   include_timestamp true
   #logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
   #logstash_format true
   <buffer>
     flush_thread_count 8
     flush_interval 5s
     chunk_limit_size 2M
     queue_limit_length 32
     retry_max_interval 30
     retry_forever true
   </buffer>
</match>

<match **>
   @type elasticsearch_dynamic
   @id out_es
   log_level info
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   #user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
   #password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
   index_name fluentd-${record['kubernetes']['container_name']}-${Time.at(time).getlocal("+05:30").strftime(@logstash_dateformat)}
   include_timestamp true
   #logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
   #logstash_format true
   <buffer>
     flush_thread_count 8
     flush_interval 5s
     chunk_limit_size 2M
     queue_limit_length 32
     retry_max_interval 30
     retry_forever true
   </buffer>
</match>
```

Can anyone please help to debug this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your pod stats? Go to Kubernetes Engine console and click on Workloads, then see what's happening to your pods. I'm assuming if your pods are crashing without any errors, they're probably running out of memory, and are getting killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a kubernetes bug as mentioned here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51376

Although this issue is closed as of now, I would suggest you to try running the same `daemonset` in `default` namespace.
Even I tried running it in `kube-system` namespace but its failing and was running successfully in the `default` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this command in order to check pods that have frequent restarts:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Then run this following command  in order to gather more information about the last known state of the container and for the associated [exit code](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status). Docker exit codes are based on [the chroot standard](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

```
kubectl describe pods [podname]
```

Doing a "kubectl describe" should provide you more information as to why your pods got terminated.